# Interview Question: Query - which sentences contain all of the words of a phrase

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I have solved the problem but was unable to come up with the most efficient problem that passes all test cases. It times out in 5 test cases.

> **Determine sentences contain all of the words of a phrase**
>   0: chris and jennifer had a fight this morning
>   1: chris went on a holiday
>   2: jennifer is in prison
>
> Query Phrases are
>   0: chris jennifer
>   1: jennifer
>   2: prison
>
> Goal is to find indexes of the matching sentences for each query or -1 if there are no matching sentence exists. Order of words does not matter.
>
> Output :
>   0
>   0 2
>   2

i.e.
First query has matching words in sentence 0, second one in sentence 0 and 1. and so on.

**Constraints**

- n: number of sentences
- m: number of prases
- n, m < 10^4
- Number of words in any sentence or query phrase is in range [1-10]
- Each word has at most 11 chars
- No word appears in more than 10 sentences
- Each word consists of upper and lower case alphabet only
- Each word must match exactly - i.e. likes and like do not match.

**Input Format:**

3
chris and jennifer had a fight this morning
chris went on a holiday
jennifer is in prison
3
chris jennifer
jennifer
prison

each 3 represents number of sentences or queries.

---

The followings were what I tried...

**1. My first solution :**

1. Make HashMap per each sentence
2. For each splitted word in phrase :
    2-1. check if all words exists in the sentence hashmap
    2-2. If so store the index
    2-3. If there is no matching sentences exist for all sentences, store -1.
3. Print result

let p = the largest number of words in a sentence
let k = the largest number of words in a query
Big O is **O(npk)**

```
public static void textQueries(List<String> sentences, List<String> queries) {
    List<Map<String, Integer>> sentenceMaps = createMaps(sentences);
    String results = queryMatcher(sentenceMaps, queries);
    System.out.println(results);
}


private static String queryMatcher(List<Map<String, Integer>> sentenceMaps, List<String> queries) {
    Map<String, Integer> wordCounter = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    List<List<String>> results = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    for (String query : queries) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < sentenceMaps.size(); j++) {
            if (isQueryFound(sentenceMaps.get(j), query, wordCounter)) {
                result.add(j + "");
            }
        }
        results.add(result);
    }
    return generateResultString(results);
}


/*
 * StringBuilder used to reduce delays of calling multiple System.out.println();
 */
private static String generateResultString(List<List<String>> results) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (List<String> matchingSentenceIndexes : results) {
        if (matchingSentenceIndexes.isEmpty()) {
            stringBuilder.append("-1\n");
        } else {
            resultStringHelper(matchingSentenceIndexes, stringBuilder);
        }
        //stringBuilder.append("\n");
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

/*
 * add " " for multiple indexes result
 */
private static void resultStringHelper(List<String> result, StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(result.get(i));
        if (i < result.size() - 1) {
            stringBuilder.append(" ");
        } else if (i == result.size() - 1) {
            stringBuilder.append("\n");
        }
    }
}
private static boolean isQueryFound(Map<String, Integer> sentenceMap, String query, Map<String, Integer> wordCounter) {
    String[] queryTokens = query.split(" ");
    for (String queryToken : queryTokens) {
        if (isMoreThan10Sentences(wordCounter, queryToken)) return false;
        if (sentenceMap.containsKey(queryToken)) {
            wordCounter.put(queryToken, wordCounter.getOrDefault(queryToken, 0) + 1);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static boolean isMoreThan10Sentences(Map<String, Integer> wordCounter, String token) {
    return wordCounter.getOrDefault(token, -1) > 10;
}

private static Map<String, Integer> initMap(String[] tokens) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String token : tokens) {
        map.put(token, 0);
    }
    return map;
}

private static List<Map<String, Integer>> createMaps(List<String> sentences) {
    List<Map<String, Integer>> maps = new ArrayList<Map<String,Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sentences.size(); i++) {
        String[] tokens = sentences.get(i).split(" ");
        maps.add(initMap(tokens));
    }
    return maps;
}
```

Timeout in the last 5 test cases.

For small test cases, the benchmark is the following on their online coding server:
Map creation time: 9.23954E-4
Query matching time: 3.85751E-4

Map generation is expensive.

---

**2. My second try:**

Similar logic but applied concurrency, as the platform supports up to 2 threads.

Multi-threading is done here :
1. Sentence -> Map generation (Concurrent map generation)
2. Query matching (Concurrent matching)

```
public static void textQueries(List<String> sentences, List<String> queries) {
    List<Map<String, Integer>> sentenceMaps = createMaps(sentences);
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    String results = queryMatcher(sentenceMaps, queries);
    System.out.println(results);

private static String queryMatcher(List<Map<String, Integer>> sentenceMaps, List<String> queries) {
    List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
    int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
    String[] results = new String[threads];
    int length = queries.size() / threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        int queryStart = length * i;
        int queryEnd = length * (i+1);
        if (i == threads -1 && queries.size() % threads != 0) queryEnd++;
        Callable<String> worker = new QueryMatcher(sentenceMaps, queries, queryStart, queryEnd);
        Future<String> submit = executor.submit(worker);
        futures.add(submit);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++) {
        try {
            results[i] = futures.get(i).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    String returnString = concaString(results);
    executor.shutdown();
    return returnString;
}

private static String concaString(String[] results) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(results[i]);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

private static String generateResultString(List<List<String>> results) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (List<String> matchingSentenceIndexes : results) {
        if (matchingSentenceIndexes.isEmpty()) {
            stringBuilder.append("-1\n");
        } else {
            resultStringHelper(matchingSentenceIndexes, stringBuilder);
        }
        //stringBuilder.append("\n");
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

private static void resultStringHelper(List<String> result, StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(result.get(i));
        if (i < result.size() - 1) {
            stringBuilder.append(" ");
        } else if (i == result.size() - 1) {
            stringBuilder.append("\n");
        }
    }
}
private static boolean isQueryFound(Map<String, Integer> sentenceMap, String query, Map<String, Integer> wordCounter) {
    String[] queryTokens = query.split(" ");
    for (String queryToken : queryTokens) {
        if (isMoreThan10Sentences(wordCounter, queryToken)) return false;
        if (sentenceMap.containsKey(queryToken)) {
            wordCounter.put(queryToken, wordCounter.getOrDefault(queryToken, 0) + 1);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static boolean isMoreThan10Sentences(Map<String, Integer> wordCounter, String token) {
    return wordCounter.getOrDefault(token, -1) > 10;
}

private static boolean isQueryFound(Map<String, Integer> sentenceMap, String query) {
    String[] queryTokens = query.split(" ");
    //Map<String, Integer> duplicateChecker = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (String queryToken : queryTokens) {
        if (sentenceMap.containsKey(queryToken)) {
            //if (!duplicateChecker(duplicateChecker, sentenceMap, queryToken))
            //return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/*
 * this method checks for the case when there are duplicate words in query
 * i.e. sentence containing 2 hello will return false of queries with 3 hello
 */
private static boolean duplicateChecker(Map<String, Integer> duplicateChecker, Map<String, Integer> sentenceMap, String queryToken) {
    if (duplicateChecker.containsKey(queryToken)) {
        if (duplicateChecker.get(queryToken) == 0) return false;
        duplicateChecker.put(queryToken, duplicateChecker.get(queryToken) - 1);
    } else {
        duplicateChecker.put(queryToken, sentenceMap.get(queryToken) - 1);
    }
    return true;
}

private static List<Map<String, Integer>> createMaps(List<String> sentences) {
    List<Map<String, Integer>> maps = new ArrayList<>();
    int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
    List<Future<List<Map<String, Integer>>>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<List<Map<String, Integer>>>>();
    int length = (sentences.size()) / threads;

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        int start = i * length;
        int end = (i+1) * length;
        if (i == threads - 1 && sentences.size() % threads != 0) end++;
        List<String> splitSentence = new ArrayList(sentences.subList(start, end));

        Callable<List<Map<String, Integer>>> worker = new MapMaker(splitSentence);
        Future<List<Map<String, Integer>>> submit = executor.submit(worker);
        futures.add(submit);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++) {
        try {
            for (Map<String, Integer> map : futures.get(i).get()) {
                maps.add(map);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    return maps;
}

private synchronized static Map<String, Integer> initMap(String[] tokens) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String token : tokens) {
        map.put(token, 0);
        //            map.put(token, map.getOrDefault(map.get(token), 1) + 1);
    }
    return map;
}


public static class MapMaker implements Callable<List<Map<String, Integer>>> {
    private List<String> sentences;

    @Override
    public List<Map<String, Integer>> call() throws Exception {
        List<Map<String, Integer>> maps = new ArrayList<Map<String,Integer>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < sentences.size(); i++) {
            String[] tokens = sentences.get(i).split(" ");
            maps.add(initMap(tokens));
        }
        return maps;
    }

    public MapMaker(List<String> sentences) {
        this.sentences = sentences;
    }
}

public static class QueryMatcher implements Callable<String> {
    private List<Map<String, Integer>> sentenceMaps;
    private List<String> queries;
    private int queryStart;
    private int queryEnd;

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        List<List<String>> results = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        for (int i = queryStart; i < queryEnd; i++) {
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
            String query = queries.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < sentenceMaps.size(); j++) {
                if (isQueryFound(sentenceMaps.get(j), query)) {
                    result.add(j + "");
                }
            }
            results.add(result);
        }
        return generateResultString(results);
    }

    public QueryMatcher(List<Map<String, Integer>> sentenceMaps, List<String> queries, int queryStart, int queryEnd) {
        this.sentenceMaps = sentenceMaps;
        this.queries = queries;
        this.queryStart = queryStart;
        this.queryEnd = queryEnd;
    }
}
```

Although I hoped for some speedup for large test case, it still gave 5 test cases timeout.

And for small test cases, it increased map generation time due to additional overhead on creating pools.

Benchmark time:
Map time: 0.007669489
Query matching time: 3.22923E-4

---

**3. My third solution - Coding the above in C++**

I questioned whether it could be Java that gives the timeout.
The platform actually gives shorter computation time for C++, so to my suprise, it still gave same 5 timeouts.

---

**4. My 4th approach Regex,**

I knew it would be slower, but I still did in futile attempt.
The Big O is actually slower here, as I need to sort each sentences by words to avoid n! permutation of regex...

```
public static void textQueries(List<String> sentences, List<String> queries) {
    stringSort(sentences);
    stringSort(queries);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    boolean isExist = false;
    for (int index = 0; index < queries.size(); index++) {
        String query = queries.get(index);
        isExist = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < sentences.size(); i++) {
            if (Matcher(buildNaturalLanguage(query), sentences.get(i))) {
                stringBuilder.append(i + " ");
                isExist = true;
            }
        }
        if (!isExist) stringBuilder.append("-1");
        if (index != queries.size() - 1) stringBuilder.append("\n");
    }
    System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
}

private static void stringSort(List<String> strings) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); ++i) {
        String string = strings.get(i);
        String[] stringParts = string.split(" ");
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Arrays.sort(stringParts);
        for (int j = 0; j < stringParts.length; j++) {
            stringBuilder.append(stringParts[j] + " ");
        }
        strings.set(i, stringBuilder.toString());  // sure I made it back to string for code cleaness but you can return String[] for efficiency.. But only minor improvement.
    }
}

private static String buildNaturalLanguage(String query) {
    // System.out.println("query " + query);
    String[] stringParts = query.split(" ");
    String regular = "(([a-zA-Z])*(\\s))*";
    for (String word : stringParts) {
        regular += word + "(\\s(([a-zA-Z])*(\\s))*)";
    }
    return regular;
}

private static boolean Matcher(String regular, String sentence) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regular);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(sentence);
    return m.find();
}
```

Result :
Not only getting timeout, it is somehow causing error (wrong answer) on 2 additional undisclosed test cases.. I have no idea why..

**Ω(nm^2 + plogp)**.. assuming regex matching is O(m)

---

I can only think of possibility of filtering some query or sentences before even runnning the main algorithm? (constraint : 10 max matching per word).

This constraint checking part is still implemented with my first and second solution however. So smarter filtering might be required.

The thing is I think the BCR - best conceivable rate is O(MNP), you would still need to go through each query and sentences, and also split them if not using regex.

I am totally lost here, how can I actually increase the speed further than this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: is the sample output wrong?  should it be 0 | 0 2 | 2?

Comment: typo, fixed sorry!

Comment: Have you run any of these with a profiler against the large test sets?  That should tell you where your bottleneck is.

Comment: I didn't have enough time to generate larget test cases myself in the test. But from the benchmark test, the HashMap appears like bottleneck. O(np).

Comment: If downvote, explain your reason, I have followed the guidelines and put my working solution as detailed as possible.

Comment: I have tried to speed up the bottleneck process by applying concurrency, the thing is, making hashmap is O(n) and usually this approach is fairly efficient in the many other interview problems. It appears that minor improvement alone isn't enough to pass all test cases...

Comment: Why not create single sentence map: `Map<String, int[]>` where key is word in sentence and the value is the sentences it occurs?

Comment: I think your "mistake" is building a hash table for each sentence.  You don't care abut the sentences, other than identifying which sentences had a word.  Build a datastructure that has a set of sentence ids for each word, where the sentence id is the position of the sentence.  Read each sentence, and then add the position of that sentence to the set of ids for each of the words in it.  Once I read and processed the last sentence, I know which sentences each word appears in.  When a query phrase has more than one word, I compute the intersection of the sets for each of the words.

Comment: Create a HashMap of String->Set<Int>. For each phrase, split it into words and query for the Sets corresponding to each word. Take the intersection of the sets for your answer.

Comment: My god, you people are too smart, if you copy and paste it to the solution field, I will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maintain a `HashMap` that will map `String`s to `Set<Int>`. The idea is to keep track of what sentences a given word appears in. We use a set instead of an array in order to support computing the intersection of two sets efficiently.

For each input sentence:

- Tokenize it into words, and add the index of the current sentence to the Set corresponding to the current token.

For each query phrase:

- Tokenize it into words.
- Query for the Set of indices corresponding to each word
- Take the intersection of all of these sets.

Time Complexity: Given that there are 10 words in each sentence, the cost of building the HashMap is O(10N log N). The cost of each query is O(10 * log(N)).

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you. If set is implemented using HashSet, building hashMap is O(P x N), and cost of querying p elements are O(P) right? and retainAll (intersection) costs O(P).

Comment: Yes, I wrote the time complexity assuming a TreeSet. You can assume O(1)  insert operations for HashSet I believe.

Comment: To confirm, you mentioned sets intersection is more efficient in your solution, but according to the documentation, it appears to be O(n) (In fact, at most 2 x (N1+N2-1)). (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) i.e. let's say we have two maps : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} union {1,3,5,7,9,11}, you still have to traverse nearly both trees no?

Comment: @zcahfg2 "No word appears in more than 10 sentences" so it hardly matters.

Comment: +1 @zcahfg2: if you are interested in further reading, this concept is called an [inverted index](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) and is a common techniques used in [information retrieval](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval)

Comment: @Michael A. Schaffrath, Thank you, will read up after lectures!

Answer (score 1):

I have following idea that may speed up , it seems similar to what Rishav proposed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("file.txt"));
        int numberOfSentences = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        Set<Integer> sentences = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Map<String, Set<Integer>> words2Sentences = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSentences; i++) {
            String words[] = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                if (!words2Sentences.containsKey(words[j])) {
                    words2Sentences.put(words[j], new HashSet<Integer>());
                }
                words2Sentences.get(words[j]).add(i);
            }
            sentences.add(i);
        }

        int numberOfPhrases = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        List<Set<Integer>> phraseResults = new ArrayList<Set<Integer>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPhrases; i++) {
            Set<String> phrases = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(sc.nextLine().split(" ")));
            Set<Integer> result = new HashSet(sentences);
            for (String s : phrases) {
                result.retainAll(words2Sentences.get(s));
            }
            phraseResults.add(result);
        }

        for (Set<Integer> set : phraseResults) {
            for (Integer i : set) {
                System.out.print(i);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void printAllQeriesIndeicesInSentence(List<String> sentences,
                                                     List<String> queries) {
   Map<Integer, List<String>> sentenceMap = new HashMap<>();
   for(int i=0; i < sentences.size(); i++){
       List<String> words = Arrays.asList(sentences.get(i).split("\\s+"));
       sentenceMap.put(i, words);
   }

   for(String query: queries){
       List<String> queryList = Arrays.asList(query.split("\\s+"));
       for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> e: sentenceMap.entrySet()){
           List<String> wordsList = e.getValue();
           if(wordsList.containsAll(queryList)){
               System.out.print(e.getKey() + " ");
           }
       }
       System.out.println();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach should work.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<set<int>> getres(vector<string> sentences, vector<string> phrases, vector<set<int>> v){
map<string,set<int>> m;
map<string,set<int>> :: iterator itr;

for(int i=0;i<sentences.size();i++){
    string temp = sentences[i];
    temp.push_back(' ');
    string word = "";
    for(int j=0;j<temp.length();j++){
        if(temp[j] == ' '){
            itr = m.find(word);
            if(itr == m.end()){
                set<int> s;
                s.insert(i);
                m.insert({word,s});
            }
            else if(itr != m.end()){
                itr->second.insert(i);
            }
            word = "";
        }
        else{
            word.push_back(temp[j]);
        }
    }
}
// for(itr = m.begin();itr!= m.end();itr++){
//     cout<<itr->first <<" ";
//     for(auto f= itr->second.begin();f!= itr->second.end();f++){
//         cout<<*f<<" ";
//     }
//     cout<<endl;
// }
for(int i=0;i<phrases.size();i++){
    string temp = phrases[i];
    temp.push_back(' ');
    string word = "";
    int flag = 0;
    set<int> s1,s2,s3;
    for(int j=0;j<temp.length();j++){
        if(temp[j] == ' '){
            // cout<<"yes";
            itr = m.find(word);
            if(itr == m.end()){
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
            else if(itr != m.end()){
                if(s1.empty()){
                    s1 = itr->second;
                }
                else{
                    set_intersection(s1.begin(),s1.end(),itr->second.begin(),itr->second.end(),inserter(s3,s3.begin()));
                    s1 = s3;
                    s3.clear();
                    if(s1.empty()){
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // for(auto f=s1.begin();f!= s1.end();f++){
                //     cout<<*f<<" ";
                // }
                // cout<<endl;
            }
            word = "";
        }
        else{
            word.push_back(temp[j]);
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1){
        s1.clear();
        s1.insert(-1);
        v[i] = s1;
        flag = 0 ;
    }
    else{
        v[i] = s1;
    }
    s1.clear();
    s2.clear();
    s3.clear();
}
return v;

}
int main() {
vector<string> sentences = {"chris and jennifer had a fight this morning", "chris went on a holiday", "jennifer is in prison"};
vector<string> phrases = {"chris jennifer", "jennifer", "prison"};
vector<set<int>> v(phrases.size());
v = getres(sentences,phrases,v);
for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
    set<int> :: iterator itr;
    for(itr = v[i].begin() ;itr != v[i].end();itr++){
        cout<<*itr<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
// cout<<"finish"<<endl;
```

}